# How to suppress android timezone changing?

Tags: android, timezone

I'm working on GUI-less Android device. All our software is C-based, no Java code at all. Sometimes Android changes time zone on device with the following message in the log:

D/AlarmManagerService(  179): Kernel timezone updated to 0 minutes west of GMT

I'd like to set time zone to GMT by default at boot time and to suppress any changes to this setting by any reason. Our device has no screen, so I can't use GUI tools. Is there any way to change Android configuration in desired way without GUI?

Comment: Change the component in the Android Framework that handles Timezone changes?

Comment: Does the device have network connection?

Comment: yes, sure. The device has network connection.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have "automatic timezone" enabled in settings, that means the device's timezone will be periodically updated from the network. This should work to disable this setting from the command line:

`adb shell settings global put auto_time_zone 0`

Might need to reboot the device afterwards, just in case.

That said, I'd like to point out that "0 minutes west of GMT" *is* GMT.